# How to add underline button into trumbow editor?

Tags: javascript, html, trumbowyg

I tried to add underline button into editor but not work.

This is code for the `trumbowyg` editor:

https://jsfiddle.net/rbyjgpjg/

```js
/* ===========================================================
 * trumbowyg.cleanpaste.js v1.0
 * Font Clean paste plugin for Trumbowyg
 * http://alex-d.github.com/Trumbowyg
 * ===========================================================
 * Author : Eric Radin
 */

/**
 * This plugin will perform a "cleaning" on any paste, in particular
 * it will clean pasted content of microsoft word document tags and classes.
 */
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  function reverse(sentString) {
    var theString = '';
    for (var i = sentString.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      theString += sentString.charAt(i);
    }
    return theString;
  }

  function checkValidTags(snippet) {
    var theString = snippet;

    // Replace uppercase element names with lowercase
    theString = theString.replace(/<[^> ]*/g, function(match) {
      return match.toLowerCase();
    });

    // Replace uppercase attribute names with lowercase
    theString = theString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
      match = match.replace(/ [^=]+=/g, function(match2) {
        return match2.toLowerCase();
      });
      return match;
    });

    // Put quotes around unquoted attributes
    theString = theString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
      match = match.replace(/( [^=]+=)([^"][^ >]*)/g, '$1\"$2\"');
      return match;
    });

    return theString;
  }

  function cleanIt(htmlBefore, htmlAfter) {
    var matchedHead = '';
    var matchedTail = '';
    var afterStart;
    var afterFinish;
    var newSnippet;

    // we need to extract the inserted block
    for (afterStart = 0; htmlAfter.charAt(afterStart) === htmlBefore.charAt(afterStart); afterStart += 1) {
      matchedHead += htmlAfter.charAt(afterStart);
    }

    // If afterStart is inside a HTML tag, move to opening brace of tag
    for (var i = afterStart; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      if (htmlBefore.charAt(i) === '<') {
        afterStart = i;
        matchedHead = htmlBefore.substring(0, afterStart);
        break;
      } else if (htmlBefore.charAt(i) === '>') {
        break;
      }
    }

    // now reverse string and work from the end in
    htmlAfter = reverse(htmlAfter);
    htmlBefore = reverse(htmlBefore);

    // Find end of both strings that matches
    for (afterFinish = 0; htmlAfter.charAt(afterFinish) === htmlBefore.charAt(afterFinish); afterFinish += 1) {
      matchedTail += htmlAfter.charAt(afterFinish);
    }

    // If afterFinish is inside a HTML tag, move to closing brace of tag
    for (var j = afterFinish; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
      if (htmlBefore.charAt(j) === '>') {
        afterFinish = j;
        matchedTail = htmlBefore.substring(0, afterFinish);
        break;
      } else if (htmlBefore.charAt(j) === '<') {
        break;
      }
    }

    matchedTail = reverse(matchedTail);

    // If there's no difference in pasted content
    if (afterStart === (htmlAfter.length - afterFinish)) {
      return false;
    }

    htmlAfter = reverse(htmlAfter);
    newSnippet = htmlAfter.substring(afterStart, htmlAfter.length - afterFinish);

    // first make sure all tags and attributes are made valid
    newSnippet = checkValidTags(newSnippet);

    // Replace opening bold tags with strong
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<b(\s+|>)/g, '<strong$1');
    // Replace closing bold tags with closing strong
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/b(\s+|>)/g, '</strong$1');

    // Replace italic tags with em
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<i(\s+|>)/g, '<em$1');
    // Replace closing italic tags with closing em
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/i(\s+|>)/g, '</em$1');

    // strip out comments -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<!(?:--[\s\S]*?--\s*)?>\s*/g, '');

    // strip out &nbsp; -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');
    // strip out extra spaces -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/ <\//gi, '</');

    while (newSnippet.indexOf('  ') !== -1) {
      var anArray = newSnippet.split('  ');
      newSnippet = anArray.join(' ');
    }

    // strip &nbsp; -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');

    // Strip out unaccepted attributes
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
      match = match.replace(/ ([^=]+)="[^"]*"/g, function(match2, attributeName) {
        if (['alt', 'href', 'src', 'title'].indexOf(attributeName) !== -1) {
          return match2;
        }
        return '';
      });
      return match;
    });

    // Final cleanout for MS Word crud
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\?xml[^>]*>/g, '');
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<[^ >]+:[^>]*>/g, '');
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/[^ >]+:[^>]*>/g, '');

    // remove unwanted tags
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<(div|span|style|meta|link){1}.*?>/gi, '');

    htmlAfter = matchedHead + newSnippet + matchedTail;
    return htmlAfter;
  }

  // clean editor
  // this will clean the inserted contents
  // it does a compare, before and after paste to determine the
  // pasted contents
  $.extend(true, $.trumbowyg, {
    plugins: {
      cleanPaste: {
        init: function(trumbowyg) {
          trumbowyg.pasteHandlers.push(function() {
            try {
              var contentBefore = trumbowyg.$ed.html();
              setTimeout(function() {
                var contentAfter = trumbowyg.$ed.html();
                contentAfter = cleanIt(contentBefore, contentAfter);
                trumbowyg.$ed.html(contentAfter);
              }, 0);
            } catch (c) {}
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);



$('#editor1').trumbowyg();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/v2.5.1/dist/trumbowyg.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/v2.5.1/dist/ui/trumbowyg.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<textarea id="editor1">This is a test.  Copy some large piece of text and 'paste' it after this line.  The cursor will reset to the first character.</textarea>
```

I tried to edit for, but couldn't find out how to edit.

Can I please get some advice?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working snippet. Basically I have taken the default button configuration (from [here](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation.html)):

```
[
    ['viewHTML'],
    ['formatting'],
    'btnGrp-semantic',
    ['superscript', 'subscript'],
    ['link'],
    ['insertImage'],
    'btnGrp-justify',
    'btnGrp-lists',
    ['horizontalRule'],
    ['removeformat'],
    ['fullscreen']
]
```

Then, I have updated third element `btn-semantic` to `['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough']`. As a result all four buttons are returned instead of the default three: `['bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough']`

```js
/* ===========================================================
 * trumbowyg.cleanpaste.js v1.0
 * Font Clean paste plugin for Trumbowyg
 * http://alex-d.github.com/Trumbowyg
 * ===========================================================
 * Author : Eric Radin
 */

/**
 * This plugin will perform a "cleaning" on any paste, in particular
 * it will clean pasted content of microsoft word document tags and classes.
 */
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  function reverse(sentString) {
    var theString = '';
    for (var i = sentString.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      theString += sentString.charAt(i);
    }
    return theString;
  }

  function checkValidTags(snippet) {
    var theString = snippet;

    // Replace uppercase element names with lowercase
    theString = theString.replace(/<[^> ]*/g, function(match) {
      return match.toLowerCase();
    });

    // Replace uppercase attribute names with lowercase
    theString = theString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
      match = match.replace(/ [^=]+=/g, function(match2) {
        return match2.toLowerCase();
      });
      return match;
    });

    // Put quotes around unquoted attributes
    theString = theString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
      match = match.replace(/( [^=]+=)([^"][^ >]*)/g, '$1\"$2\"');
      return match;
    });

    return theString;
  }

  function cleanIt(htmlBefore, htmlAfter) {
    var matchedHead = '';
    var matchedTail = '';
    var afterStart;
    var afterFinish;
    var newSnippet;

    // we need to extract the inserted block
    for (afterStart = 0; htmlAfter.charAt(afterStart) === htmlBefore.charAt(afterStart); afterStart += 1) {
      matchedHead += htmlAfter.charAt(afterStart);
    }

    // If afterStart is inside a HTML tag, move to opening brace of tag
    for (var i = afterStart; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      if (htmlBefore.charAt(i) === '<') {
        afterStart = i;
        matchedHead = htmlBefore.substring(0, afterStart);
        break;
      } else if (htmlBefore.charAt(i) === '>') {
        break;
      }
    }

    // now reverse string and work from the end in
    htmlAfter = reverse(htmlAfter);
    htmlBefore = reverse(htmlBefore);

    // Find end of both strings that matches
    for (afterFinish = 0; htmlAfter.charAt(afterFinish) === htmlBefore.charAt(afterFinish); afterFinish += 1) {
      matchedTail += htmlAfter.charAt(afterFinish);
    }

    // If afterFinish is inside a HTML tag, move to closing brace of tag
    for (var j = afterFinish; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
      if (htmlBefore.charAt(j) === '>') {
        afterFinish = j;
        matchedTail = htmlBefore.substring(0, afterFinish);
        break;
      } else if (htmlBefore.charAt(j) === '<') {
        break;
      }
    }

    matchedTail = reverse(matchedTail);

    // If there's no difference in pasted content
    if (afterStart === (htmlAfter.length - afterFinish)) {
      return false;
    }

    htmlAfter = reverse(htmlAfter);
    newSnippet = htmlAfter.substring(afterStart, htmlAfter.length - afterFinish);

    // first make sure all tags and attributes are made valid
    newSnippet = checkValidTags(newSnippet);

    // Replace opening bold tags with strong
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<b(\s+|>)/g, '<strong$1');
    // Replace closing bold tags with closing strong
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/b(\s+|>)/g, '</strong$1');

    // Replace italic tags with em
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<i(\s+|>)/g, '<em$1');
    // Replace closing italic tags with closing em
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/i(\s+|>)/g, '</em$1');

    // strip out comments -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<!(?:--[\s\S]*?--\s*)?>\s*/g, '');

    // strip out &nbsp; -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');
    // strip out extra spaces -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/ <\//gi, '</');

    while (newSnippet.indexOf('  ') !== -1) {
      var anArray = newSnippet.split('  ');
      newSnippet = anArray.join(' ');
    }

    // strip &nbsp; -cgCraft
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');

    // Strip out unaccepted attributes
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
      match = match.replace(/ ([^=]+)="[^"]*"/g, function(match2, attributeName) {
        if (['alt', 'href', 'src', 'title'].indexOf(attributeName) !== -1) {
          return match2;
        }
        return '';
      });
      return match;
    });

    // Final cleanout for MS Word crud
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\?xml[^>]*>/g, '');
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<[^ >]+:[^>]*>/g, '');
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/[^ >]+:[^>]*>/g, '');

    // remove unwanted tags
    newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<(div|span|style|meta|link){1}.*?>/gi, '');

    htmlAfter = matchedHead + newSnippet + matchedTail;
    return htmlAfter;
  }

  // clean editor
  // this will clean the inserted contents
  // it does a compare, before and after paste to determine the
  // pasted contents
  $.extend(true, $.trumbowyg, {
    plugins: {
      cleanPaste: {
        init: function(trumbowyg) {
          trumbowyg.pasteHandlers.push(function() {
            try {
              var contentBefore = trumbowyg.$ed.html();
              setTimeout(function() {
                var contentAfter = trumbowyg.$ed.html();
                contentAfter = cleanIt(contentBefore, contentAfter);
                trumbowyg.$ed.html(contentAfter);
              }, 0);
            } catch (c) {}
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);



$('#editor1').trumbowyg({
    btns: 
    [
        ['viewHTML'],
        ['formatting'],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough'],
        ['superscript', 'subscript'],
        ['link'],
        ['insertImage'],
        'btnGrp-justify',
        'btnGrp-lists',
        ['horizontalRule'],
        ['removeformat'],
        ['fullscreen']
    ]
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/v2.5.1/dist/trumbowyg.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/v2.5.1/dist/ui/trumbowyg.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<textarea id="editor1">This is a test.  Copy some large piece of text and 'paste' it after this line.  The cursor will reset to the first character.</textarea>
```